# In Nobilis what is the positive benefit of a Bond?

Tags: character-creation, relationship-mechanic, nobilis

Bonds seem to be more than just a liability, these are the things that are important to a character, and given the very correspondence driven nature of the Nobilis cosmology would see to be a strength.

How is the strength aspect of Bonds represented in the rules? Is this a good area to house rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bond are a liability to a Noble. They are an example of signaling to the referee, "I think it would be cool to play with this". I think for a lot of groups out there are in fact ignore them. My players did not like them and I generally did not use them much. Once I started to role-play a lot with there Anchors there had to spend Bond points on them.

I did a sequence of adventures using the Nobles' Anchor called [Janus](http://www.ironfort.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?JanusRPG), which I did run as a Heroic level fantasy game.